# Comparing value in document to value in previous document for each document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where I'm storing a point of arrival and a point of departure and I need to check if the point of departure is the same as the point of departure of the previous document for each document.

```
{
departure:A
arrival:B
}
{
departure:B
arrival:C
}
{
departure:H
arrival:J
}
```

In this collection I should only be getting the second document since it's the only one where the departure(B) equals the arrival of the previous document(B).

In SQL it would be as simple as TABLE.DEPARTURE = TABLE.ARRIVAL+1,
is there any way of doing something like that in Mongo?

Comment: Do it in javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read this document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/

Comment: Thanks! I get it now!